# How does this query populate data?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-redshift

It is my understanding that when this query runs it would not populate any data any number of times it runs because of the where clause

```
where c.company_id = lot.company_id
  and p.product_id = lot.product_id 
  and l.packlevel_id = lot.packlevel_id
```

It looks to me that at the very beginning when the table `fact_table_lot` is empty the where clause would return with empty data because it would not find anything in an empty table and it would happen everytime. Is my understanding wrong?

```
insert into fact_table_lot(company_id, product_id, packlevel_id, l_num, sn_count, comm_loct, comm_start, commdate_end, man_date, exp_date, user_id, created_datetime)
select c.company_id, p.product_id, l.packlevel_id, l_num, sn_count, comm_loct, comm_start, commdate_end, man_date, exp_date, user_id, sysdate
from staging_serials s 
  left outer join fact_table_lot lot on s.lotnumber = lot.l_num
  join company c on c.lsc_company_id = s.companyid
  join product p on s.compositeprodcode = p.compositeprodcode
  join level l on l.unit_of_measure = p.packaginguom
where c.company_id = lot.company_id
  and p.product_id = lot.product_id 
  and l.packlevel_id = lot.packlevel_id
  and lot.created_datetime is null
```

Comment: The fact_table_lot is on the right hand side of your left outer join. A left outer join will show all rows on the left hand table (staging_serial) and for all rows which don't match, will have all columns with the value NULL for fact_table_lot. If you name the join to fact_table_lot and INNER JOIN, then yes, no rows will be returned

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your query `staging_serials s left outer join fact_table_lot lot on s.lotnumber= lot.l_num` this will give the result set containing all records from `staging_serials` and since fact table is empty null values for those column from fact table. If you want no records to be returned use a `inner join` instead of `left join`.